# compareTo() String / Merge sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm having a problem printing out the descending order of my array. The array order goes like (Title,Studio,Year). 
 I have the correct order but I can't print a ascending order it can only print a descending order.  Example

`Movie2 a = new Movie2("The Muppets Take Manhattan","Columbia Tristar", 2001);
       Movie2 b = new Movie2("Mulan Special Edition","Disney", 2004);
       Movie2 c = new Movie2("Shrek2", "Dreamworks",2004);`

```
  public static void sortTitles(Movie2[] a, int low, int high)
    {
        if ( low == high )
            return;

        int mid = ( low + high ) / 2;

        mergeTitle( a, low, mid, high);
    }  

    public static void mergeTitle( Movie2[] a, int low, int mid, int high )
    {
        Movie2[] temp = new Movie2[ high - low + 1 ];

        int i = low, j = mid + 1, n = 0;


        while ( i <= mid || j <= high )
        {

            int result= a[ i ].getTitle().compareTo(a[ j ].getTitle());
            int result2= a[ j ].getTitle().compareTo(a[ i ].getTitle());
            if ( i > mid )
            {
                temp[ n ] = a[ j ];
                j++;
            }
            else if ( j > high )
            {
                temp[ n ] = a[ i ];
                i++;
            }
            else if ( result < result2 )
            {
                temp[ n ] = a[ i ];
                i++;
            }

            else
            {
                temp[ n ] = a[ j ];
                j++;
            }
            n++;
        }

        for ( int k = low ; k <= high ; k++ )
            a[ k ] = temp[ k - low ];

    } // end of merge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want descending order, as you already do:

```
int result= a[ i ].getTitle().compareTo(a[ j ].getTitle());
int result2= a[ j ].getTitle().compareTo(a[ i ].getTitle());
```

Ascending is the *opposite* of descending, so just negativize the comparisons:

```
int result= a[ i ].getTitle().compareTo(a[ j ].getTitle()) * -1;
int result2= a[ j ].getTitle().compareTo(a[ i ].getTitle()) * -1;
```

To optionally do it, you could pass in a boolean:

```
int result= a[ i ].getTitle().compareTo(a[ j ].getTitle()) *
   (isAscending ? -1 : 1);
int result2= a[ j ].getTitle().compareTo(a[ i ].getTitle()) *
   (isAscending ? -1 : 1);
```

(You say your sorting works well descending, and this answer assumes that's true. I've not verified it.)